# loading multiple music media in mediaplayer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

it does not load up the songs declare in the switch case

> ```
>     final ArrayList<Integer> playlist;
>
>
>     playlist = new ArrayList<>();
>     playlist.add(R.raw.honey);
>     playlist.add(R.raw.anger);
>     playlist.add(R.raw.contempt);
>     playlist.add(R.raw.disgust);
>     playlist.add(R.raw.fear);
>     playlist.add(R.raw.happy);
>     playlist.add(R.raw.sadness);
>     playlist.add(R.raw.surprise);
>
>
>     MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
>     Button play = findViewById(R.id.play);
>     Button pause = findViewById(R.id.pause);
>     Button jumpToMainActivity = findViewById(R.id.jumpToMainActivity);
>
>     mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(0));
>
>     switch (final_detected_emotion){
>         case "anger":
>             mediaPlayer.reset();
>             mediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(1));
>             break;
>         case "contempt":
>             mediaPlayer.reset();
>             mediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(2));
>             break;
>         case "disgust":
>             mediaPlayer.reset();
>             mediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(3));
>             break;
>         case "fear":
>             mediaPlayer.reset();
>             mediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(4));
>             break;
>         case "happy":
>             mediaPlayer.reset();
>             mediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(5));
>             break;
>         case "sadness":
>             mediaPlayer.reset();
>             mediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(6));
>             break;
>         case "surprise":
>             mediaPlayer.reset();
>             mediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(7));
>             break;
>     }
>     final MediaPlayer finalMediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
>
>     play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             finalMediaPlayer.start();
>         }
>     });
> ```

it only play the honey song . the string (final_detected_emotion) passed changes but the song does not changes.

will i delete the mediaplayer object

i have made the app which play songs on detected emotion

Comment: what is the value of final_detected_emotion?

Comment: it is a string which is passed from main activity to second activity . it can be any key comparison made in switch case like anger ,fear

Comment: I think it's not matching with the string coming from the main activity. Here there is no equal ignore-case so you have to pass the data the same way you put inside switch case.

Comment: its all lowercase

Comment: by default i am passing anger string but did not play anger song

Comment: the mediaplayer does not play song which is in switch case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    switch (final_detected_emotion){
        case "anger":
           mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(1));
            break;
        case "contempt":
           mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(2));
            break;
        case "disgust":
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(3));
            break;
        case "fear":
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(4));
            break;
        case "happy":
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(5));
            break;
        case "sadness":
           mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(6));
            break;
        case "surprise":
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(7));
            break;
        default :
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,playlist.get(0));
    }
```

Comment: can you tell me how to access hotspot setting in android or any classes for hotspot  , like how many devices connected . please do share link .